# Firestore Paginating data + Snapshot listener

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with Firestore right now and have a little bit of a problem with pagination.
Basically, I have a collection (assume 10 items) where each item has some data and a timestamp.

Now, I am fetching the first 3 items like this:

```
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("collectionPath")
    .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
    .limit(to: 3)
    .addSnapshotListener(snapshotListener())
```

Inside my snapshot listener, I save the last document from the snapshot, in order to use that as a starting point for my next page.

So, at some time I will request the next page of items like this:

```
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("collectionPath")
    .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
    .start(afterDocument: lastDocument)
    .limit(to: 3)
    .addSnapshotListener(snapshotListener2()) // Note that this is a new snapshot listener, I don't know how I could reuse the first one
```

Now I have the items from index 0 to index 5 (in total 6) in my frontend. Neat!

If the document at index 4 now updates its timestamp to the newest timestamp of the whole collection, things start to go down.
Remember that the timestamp determines its position on account of the order clause!

What I expected to happen was, that after the changes are applied, I still show 6 items (and still ordered by their timestamps)

What happened was, that after the changes are applied, I have only 5 items remaining, since the item that got pushed out of the first snapshot is not added to the second snapshot automatically.

Am I missing something about Pagination with Firestore?

EDIT: As requested, I post some more code here:
This is my function to return a snapshot listener. Well, and the two methods I use to request the first page and then the second page I posted already above

```
private func snapshotListener() -> FIRQuerySnapshotBlock {
    let index = self.index
    return { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snap = querySnapshot, error == nil else {
            log.error(error)
            return
        }

        // Save the last doc, so we can later use pagination to retrieve further chats
        if snap.count == self.limit {
            self.lastDoc = snap.documents.last
        } else {
            self.lastDoc = nil
        }

        let offset = index * self.limit

        snap.documentChanges.forEach() { diff in
            switch diff.type {
            case .added:
                log.debug("added chat at index: \(diff.newIndex), offset: \(offset)")
                self.tVHandler.dataManager.insert(item: Chat(dictionary: diff.document.data() as NSDictionary), at: IndexPath(row: Int(diff.newIndex) + offset, section: 0), in: nil)

            case .removed:
                log.debug("deleted chat at index: \(diff.oldIndex), offset: \(offset)")
                self.tVHandler.dataManager.remove(itemAt: IndexPath(row: Int(diff.oldIndex) + offset, section: 0), in: nil)

            case .modified:
                if diff.oldIndex == diff.newIndex {
                    log.debug("updated chat at index: \(diff.oldIndex), offset: \(offset)")
                    self.tVHandler.dataManager.update(item: Chat(dictionary: diff.document.data() as NSDictionary), at: IndexPath(row: Int(diff.oldIndex) + offset, section: 0), in: nil)
                } else {
                    log.debug("moved chat at index: \(diff.oldIndex), offset: \(offset) to index: \(diff.newIndex), offset: \(offset)")
                    self.tVHandler.dataManager.move(item: Chat(dictionary: diff.document.data() as NSDictionary), from: IndexPath(row: Int(diff.oldIndex) + offset, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: Int(diff.newIndex) + offset, section: 0), in: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

So again, I am asking if I can have one snapshot listener that listens for changes in more than one page I requested from Firestore

Comment: Share your code and how do you call for pagination so others could help you

Comment: @AliAdil I added some more code (it is in fact all of what I use now)

Comment: Here is the link to my working solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914090/3412051

Comment: I know this is an old thread, however, I wrote something about this now. Maybe it helps you - https://rizwaniqbal.com/posts/paginating-firestore-collections-with-snapshot-listeners/

Comment: @skaldesh Did you got the solution ?

Comment: @automaticAllDramatic Correct me if I am wrong, but your solution uses a client side workaround with a Map in order to keep the collections in sync. What I wanted back then is a Firestore solution.

Comment: @skaldesh yes, you are right. Its on the client side. I have used a variety of methods since writing this. Most recently, I maintain a document on firestore with a counter in extreme cases :) I use firestore only to sync clients now, have moved most of my logic to a sql db

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I contacted the guys over at Firebase Google Group for help, and they were able to tell me that my use case is not yet supported.
Thanks to Kato Richardson for attending to my problem!

For anyone interested in the details, see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/L-maF89Hc9M)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to get this working in the end?

Comment: No, we decided to accept the tradeoff to only have the first page load changes. We can do that, since we implemented a simple chat, where new messages only occur at the beginning. But it is far from a perfect solution :/

Comment: Ok thanks anyway :) I found this which may be helpful: https://medium.com/@wcandillon/firebase-live-pagination-474748853e52

Comment: Interesting! But I think the way he described there is exactly what I tried. He does not try to insert one item in a page that causes items of this page to be pushed into another page... What was my problem here. Thanks for the link, though!

Comment: I already implemented a working solution for this in Objective-C and it's working in my app, here is the link for it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914090/3412051

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same use case today and I have successfully implemented a working solution in Objective C client. Below is the algorithm if anyone wants to apply in their program and I will really appreciate if google-cloud-firestore team can put my solution on their page.

**Use Case:** A feature to allow paginating a long list of recent chats along with the option to attach real time listeners to update the list to have chat with most recent message on top.

**Solution:** This can be made possible by using pagination logic like we do for other long lists and attaching real time listener with limit set to 1:

Step 1: On page load fetch the chats using pagination query as below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     [self fetchChats];
}

-(void)fetchChats {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
     FIRQuery *paginateChatsQuery = [[[self.db collectionWithPath:MAGConstCollectionNameChats]queryOrderedByField:MAGConstFieldNameTimestamp descending:YES]queryLimitedTo:MAGConstPageLimit];
    if(self.arrChats.count > 0){
        FIRDocumentSnapshot *lastChatDocument = self.arrChats.lastObject;
        paginateChatsQuery = [paginateChatsQuery queryStartingAfterDocument:lastChatDocument];
    }
    [paginateChatsQuery getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot * _Nullable snapshot, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (snapshot == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error fetching documents: %@", error);
            return;
        }
        ///2. Observe chat updates if not attached
        if(weakSelf.chatObserverState == ChatObserverStateNotAttached) {
            weakSelf.chatObserverState = ChatObserverStateAttaching;
            [weakSelf observeChats];
        }

        if(snapshot.documents.count < MAGConstPageLimit) {
            weakSelf.noMoreData = YES;
        }
        else {
            weakSelf.noMoreData = NO;
        }

        [weakSelf.arrChats addObjectsFromArray:snapshot.documents];
        [weakSelf.tblVuChatsList reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Step 2: On success callback of "fetchAlerts" method attach the observer for real time updates only once with limit set to 1.

```
-(void)observeChats {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    self.chatsListener = [[[[self.db collectionWithPath:MAGConstCollectionNameChats]queryOrderedByField:MAGConstFieldNameTimestamp descending:YES]queryLimitedTo:1]addSnapshotListener:^(FIRQuerySnapshot * _Nullable snapshot, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (snapshot == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error fetching documents: %@", error);
            return;
        }
        if(weakSelf.chatObserverState == ChatObserverStateAttaching) {
            weakSelf.chatObserverState = ChatObserverStateAttached;
        }

        for (FIRDocumentChange *diff in snapshot.documentChanges) {
            if (diff.type == FIRDocumentChangeTypeAdded) {
                ///New chat added
                NSLog(@"Added chat: %@", diff.document.data);
                FIRDocumentSnapshot *chatDoc = diff.document;
                [weakSelf handleChatUpdates:chatDoc];

            }
            else if (diff.type == FIRDocumentChangeTypeModified) {
                NSLog(@"Modified chat: %@", diff.document.data);
                FIRDocumentSnapshot *chatDoc = diff.document;
                [weakSelf handleChatUpdates:chatDoc];
            }
            else if (diff.type == FIRDocumentChangeTypeRemoved) {
                NSLog(@"Removed chat: %@", diff.document.data);
            }
        }
    }];

}
```

Step 3. On listener callback check for document changes and handle only **FIRDocumentChangeTypeAdded** and **FIRDocumentChangeTypeModified** events and ignore the **FIRDocumentChangeTypeRemoved** event. We are doing this by calling "**handleChatUpdates**" method for both **FIRDocumentChangeTypeAdded** and **FIRDocumentChangeTypeModified** event in which we are first trying to find the matching chat document from local list and if it exist we are removing it from the list and then we are adding the new document received from listener callback and adding it to the beginning of the list.

```
-(void)handleChatUpdates:(FIRDocumentSnapshot *)chatDoc {
    NSInteger chatIndex = [self getIndexOfMatchingChatDoc:chatDoc];
    if(chatIndex != NSNotFound) {
        ///Remove this object
        [self.arrChats removeObjectAtIndex:chatIndex];
    }
    ///Insert this chat object at the beginning of the array
     [self.arrChats insertObject:chatDoc atIndex:0];

    ///Refresh the tableview
    [self.tblVuChatsList reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)getIndexOfMatchingChatDoc:(FIRDocumentSnapshot *)chatDoc {
    NSInteger chatIndex = 0;
    for (FIRDocumentSnapshot *chatDocument in self.arrChats) {
        if([chatDocument.documentID isEqualToString:chatDoc.documentID]) {
            return chatIndex;
        }
        chatIndex++;
    }
    return NSNotFound;
}
```

Step 4. Reload the tableview to see the changes.

Comment: you might have noticed Swift tag! Can you convert the Objective-C to Swift?

Comment: As there is no one yet to come up with the solution of paginating data along with listener so I gave the solution in the language I am comfortable with. I think solution is more important rather than language for now and you can easily convert it to swift by reading the explanation I gave in simple English as well as going through the code.

Comment: This solution does not work if the app requires real-time updates to existing documents, because you're only listening to the most recent document and the rest are fetched with `getDocuments`.

Comment: I considered the use case of real time updates of recent chat list in which I am observing last Message timestamp which will always be updated whenever there is a new update(or message).
You can also make this work in your use case as well by updating the timestamp(say a field named as updatedAt) whenever a document gets updated and observing that field instead.

Comment: @willbattel I just replied to your Google post with detailed explanation on this thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/L-maF89Hc9M
I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is to create 1 maintainer query - listener to observe on  those removed item from first query, and we will update it every time there's new message coming.

Answer (score 0):

To make pagination with snapshot listener first we have to create `reference point document` from the collection.After that we are listening to collection based on that `reference point document`.

Let's you have a collection called `messages` and timestamp called `createdAt` with each document in that collection.

```
//get messages
getMessages(){

//first we will fetch the very last/latest document.

//to hold listeners
listnerArray=[];

const very_last_document= await this.afs.collectons('messages')
    .ref
    .limit(1)
    .orderBy('createdAt','desc')
    .get({ source: 'server' });

 
 //if very_last.document.empty property become true,which means there is no messages 
  //present till now ,we can go with a query without having a limit

 //else we have to apply the limit

 if (!very_last_document.empty) {

    
    const start = very_last_document.docs[very_last_document.docs.length - 1].data().createdAt;
    //listner for new messages
   //all new message will be registered on this listener
    const listner_1 = this.afs.collectons('messages')
    .ref
    .orderBy('createdAt','desc')
    .endAt(start)     <== this will make sure the query will fetch up to 'start' point(including 'start' point document)
    .onSnapshot(messages => {

        for (const message of messages .docChanges()) {
          if (message .type === "added")
            //do the job...
          if (message.type === "modified")
            //do the job...
          if (message.type === "removed")
           //do the job ....
        }
      },
        err => {
          //on error
        })

    //old message will be registered on this listener
    const listner_2 = this.afs.collectons('messages')
    .ref
    .orderBy('createdAt','desc')
    .limit(20)
    .startAfter(start)   <== this will make sure the query will fetch after the 'start' point
    .onSnapshot(messages => {

        for (const message of messages .docChanges()) {
          if (message .type === "added")
            //do the job...
          if (message.type === "modified")
            //do the job...
          if (message.type === "removed")
           //do the job ....
        }
       this.listenerArray.push(listner_1, listner_2);
      },
        err => {
          //on error
        })
  } else {
    //no document found!
   //very_last_document.empty = true
    const listner_1 = this.afs.collectons('messages')
    .ref
    .orderBy('createdAt','desc')
    .onSnapshot(messages => {

        for (const message of messages .docChanges()) {
          if (message .type === "added")
            //do the job...
          if (message.type === "modified")
            //do the job...
          if (message.type === "removed")
           //do the job ....
        }
      },
        err => {
          //on error
        })
    this.listenerArray.push(listner_1);
  }

}


//to load more messages
LoadMoreMessage(){

//Assuming messages array holding the the message we have fetched


 //getting the last element from the array messages.
 //that will be the starting point of our next batch
 const endAt = this.messages[this.messages.length-1].createdAt

  const listner_2 = this.getService
  .collections('messages')
  .ref
  .limit(20)
  .orderBy('createdAt', "asc")    <== should be in 'asc' order
  .endBefore(endAt)    <== Getting the 20 documnents (the limit we have applied) from the point 'endAt';
.onSnapshot(messages => {

if (messages.empty && this.messages.length)
  this.messages[this.messages.length - 1].hasMore = false;

for (const message of messages.docChanges()) {
  if (message.type === "added") 
  //do the job...

  if (message.type === "modified")
    //do the job

  if (message.type === "removed")
    //do the job
}

},
 err => {
    //on error
 })

 this.listenerArray.push(listner_2)



}
```