# In order to maintain live updates while also paginating using Firestore, should I maintain an array of listeners (`ListenerRegistration`)?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

First, yes I've looked at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182780/firestore-paginating-data-snapshot-listener#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182780/firestore-paginating-data-snapshot-listener#_=_). However I would like to believe there is a solution for this, so I am wondering if the following method would be the proper implementation (and solution).

I'm building a chat application and do not want to download all of the messages for a channel at once, so I checked out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors. They have a `first` snapshot listener listening for changing on the first 25 cities. However, it's not immediately clear how listening works for all following pages.

What I'm thinking is that a listener should be created for each page and is responsible for listening to changes for its respective page to look something like this https://gist.github.com/michael-mckenna/7d4adb7817b6eca3c734d7c602785698

However that still looks rather hacky. However, given what Firestore provides, is maintaining this array of listeners the solution to supporting live-updating + pagination?

Comment: The reason there is no ready-built solution for Cloud Firestore (with realtime updates) is that it is quite complex. One approach is indeed to use multiple listeners, one per page. Using that approach you will need to merge the results from those listeners together, and indeed will need a list to track those listeners. It doesn't have to be hacky, but it's definitely quite complex.

Comment: Your solution looks good to me, but there is a potential edge case (related to the complexity that Frank mentioned). Once you have a page listener set up, if an item is added within that page, then it'll push out the last item. Unless you adjust the subsequent page listeners with a new startAt() to compensate, then you'll have a gap in your results. :-/  The complex workaround is to only do a limit() query to determine the "end" of the page, and then switch to a startAt().endAt() query so that both endpoints of the page are fixed and there can't be any gaps between pages.